# Cannot update table entry in python-netsnmpagent

Tags: python, c, snmp, agent, net-snmp

I use python-netsnmpagent module. I've already used raw netsnmp library example which is on below link

https://github.com/circonus-labs/net-snmp/blob/master/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt

This example can update tables and it work like a charm by below commands

```
snmpwalk  -v 2c -c public -mPATH/TO/MY-MIB/MY-NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt localhost:5555 netSnmpIETFWGTable
NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::nsIETFWGChair1."snmpv3" = STRING: "string1"
NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::nsIETFWGChair2."snmpv3" = STRING: "string2"
```

but when I used the example of the python-netsnmpagent which is on below link

https://github.com/pief/python-netsnmpagent/blob/master/examples/run_simple_agent.sh

Update the entry of a table was shown me below error:

```
snmpset -v 2c -c simple -mPATH/TO/MY-MIB/MY-NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt localhost:5555 MY-NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::nsIETFWGChair1.\"snmpv3\" s "STRING"
 Error in packet.
 Reason: notWritable (That object does not support modification)
 Failed object: MY-NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::nsIETFWGChair1."snmpv3"
```

Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: Please, why the C tag?

Comment: Because python-netsnmpagent module is an wrapper of the C library of netsnmp. I thought this problem originate the c wrapper.

Comment: Well, isn't then everything a wrapper around some C stuff? ;-)

Comment: Maybe yes, but everything is not a wrapper of net-snmp c library. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi [Ehsan Ahmadi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5644721/ehsan-ahmadi)

You don't have write access to the table, because you did not enable this access when creating the table. Use this patch to enable this access.

```
diff --git a/examples/simple_agent.py b/examples/simple_agent.py
index ba809ff..abbfa53 100755
--- a/examples/simple_agent.py
+++ b/examples/simple_agent.py
@@ -143,12 +143,13 @@ firstTable = agent.Table(
        agent.DisplayString()
    ],
    columns = [
-       (2, agent.DisplayString("Unknown place")),
-       (3, agent.Integer32(0))
+       (2, agent.DisplayString("Unknown place"), 1),
+       (3, agent.Integer32(0), 1)
    ],
    counterobj = agent.Unsigned32(
        oidstr = "SIMPLE-MIB::firstTableNumber"
-   )
+   ),
+        extendable = True
 )

 # Add the first table row
```

GOOD LUCK